# c++ operator overloading. Function to get private value from overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

I have trouble getting the "print" function in this class to get the right total

```
class PRN {
private:
typedef pair < string, int > P;   
int sz, // map size – no of distinct words
cnt, // counter for printing
total; // no of words
public:
// constructor
PRN ( const int& s = 1, const int& c = 0, const int& t = 0 ){
    cnt= c;
    total = t;
        sz = s;        
}
void operator ( ) ( const P& p ){
    total += p.second;
    cout << total;
}// overloaded operator, where P is defined as
// typedef pair < string, int > P;

void print () const{
    cout <<"no of words in output list : " << total << endl;
}

};
```

then in my main i call

```
PRN p (m.size());
    for_each(m.begin(),m.end(),p);
    p.print();
```

m is a map containing some values(string, int);
The operator is adding because im printing them and I can see they are getting added but when I called p.print() it returns zero for the "total".

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Your code is an example of where I would hesitate to use operator overloading. It isn't immediately clear what the operator does to your class. Use a well titled function name instead.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the behavior of `for_each` - the standard doesn't guarantee that `for_each` won't copy `p` internally while doing its work. As a result, function-like objects like this that have state generally don't work well with the standard library functions. Personally, I've always thought this behavior is weird and undermines a lot of the point of having function-like objects, but that's the hand we've been dealt.

Depending on how you're using it, you may be able to get more-or-less the behavior that you want by making `total` a static member of `PRN`, so that there's only one `total` value anywhere that all `PRN` objects use. A drawback is that the next `for_each` would pick up where you left off instead of starting from scratch, but you might be able to mitigate that by doing things like having the `PRN` constructor reset `total` to zero (on the assumption that `PRN` objects don't live very long and are created very close to where they are used).

Another possibility would be to have `PRN` objects contain a pointer to another object that actually contains the total, like this:

```
class PRN
{
private:
    struct Storage
    {
        int total;
    };

    Storage *s;
public:
    PRN():
        s(new Storage)
    {
    }

    ~PRN()
    {
        delete s;
    }

    void operator()(const P& p)
    {
        s->total += p.second;
        ...
    }

    ...
};
```

Using this approach, it doesn't matter if `for_each` copies `p`, because the copy will point to the same Storage object that the original did.

Comment: I made total a static int and it had some errors when compiling.
undefined reference to `PRN::total'

Comment: Is it saying that the undefined reference is in the code you've shown, or somewhere else? I don't see anything that would cause a problem, but if you can give me more information I might be able to help. I've also added a second possible solution that you might prefer.

Comment: @AndreEscudero: If you *declare* a `static` member, you have to *define* it *outside* the `class` declaration: `int PRN::number_of_words;`

Comment: @Johnsyweb Right, of course, I should have remembered that. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @Johnsyweb thanks. That solved the problem. Well this was for a hw assigment and the directions where to use the class PRN. The class was already made I just had to implemented with the correct stuff and total was not static. But it does seem to work by making total a static member.

Comment: @AndreEscudero: N.B: Making this `static` means that the state is shared across all instances of the class and not just all copies of `p`, which is the advantage of Ben S.'s storage approach.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to use a shared pointer for the data to be shared between copies of the class. Like so: http://ideone.com/Qp4oli